# Convert DOCX file to PDF file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm converting a docx file to PDF using [libreconv](https://github.com/DocSpring/libreconv) gem and I want to keep the same fonts that I'm using inside the docx file but the generated PDF does not have the same fonts

What is the solution for this issue?

Or is there any other gem to convert from Docx file to PDF with High quality
I don't want to convert the docx file to HTML first, so PDF KIT and wicked_pdf gems will not work for me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried installing the fonts in the same system where you're running libreconv?

Comment: Yes, I did with no luck, I have ubuntu wsl on windows 10 and I installed the fonts using command line but it did not work, I don't know if the fonts failed to install or the gem not picking them up, is there anyway to be sure?

Comment: If it's ubuntu-based you can run `fc-list - list available fonts` too see the list of installed fonts.

Comment: Fixed :) , the fonts was not available on ubuntu, it's looking good now, thank you Pedro, please add your answer so I can accept it

Comment: No worries, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your fonts are installed in the system where you're running `libreconv`.

If it's ubuntu-based you can run `fc-list - list available fonts` to see the list of installed fonts.